# Context Menu on a row of TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, contextmenu

I am using JavaFX and my application has a table and I can add elements to the table but I want to create a context menu that displays on a row when I right click on that row.

What I have...

In Scene Builder I have a method that runs on when the Context Menu is activated but that isn't exactly what I want. This would be fine really because I am programmatically grab the selected item from the table whenever I want. The issue, if I keep what I currently have, is getting the context menu to popup at the selected element.

contextMenu is the context menu with menu items.
connectedUsers is the TableView

The following is the closest I can get, but this shows the context menu at the bottom of the TableView

```
contextMenu.show(connectedUsers, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

Comment: For a really full discussion of ContextMenus on TableViews, TableRows, and TableCells, see [this](https://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2013/12/30/javafx-tableviews-with-contextmenus/)

Comment: Link above broken so here's an alternative that should work:  https://web.archive.org/web/20170328115801/https://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2013/12/30/javafx-tableviews-with-contextmenus/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this..

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem("Menu 1");
cm.getItems().add(mi1);
MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem("Menu 2");
cm.getItems().add(mi2);

table.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        if(t.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            cm.show(table, t.getScreenX(), t.getScreenY());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Could you add also an example of a `setOnAction` given to one of the items? Thanks

Comment: @Robb1 I hope, it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344244/minimize-panel-button/21347019#21347019

Comment: This is not installed on the row but in the table instead. Therefore, if the table is empty, the context menu is going to be displayed...

Comment: in case your IDE doesn't recognize MouseButton, the import javafx.scene.input.* will find it

Comment: This solution will display a context menu even if table has no rows inside it.. Also it does not add the context menu based on row, rather it adds based on right click. So if you right click on table header also, still you see the context menu, which seems not appropriate.

Answer (score 22):

I believe that the best solution would be this as discussed in [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140406113922/https://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2013/12/30/javafx-tableviews-with-contextmenus/).

```
table.setRowFactory(
    new Callback<TableView<Person>, TableRow<Person>>() {
        @Override
        public TableRow<Person> call(TableView<Person> tableView) {
            final TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();
            final ContextMenu rowMenu = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem editItem = new MenuItem("Edit");
            editItem.setOnAction(...);
            MenuItem removeItem = new MenuItem("Delete");
            removeItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    table.getItems().remove(row.getItem());
                }
            });
            rowMenu.getItems().addAll(editItem, removeItem);
            
            // only display context menu for non-empty rows:
            row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
              Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
              .then((ContextMenu) null)
              .otherwise(rowMenu);
            return row;
    }
});
```

Comment: Since this sets the menu labels at the time of row creation, it doesn't seem like you can easily do custom menus which reflect the data in each row. Ex. prompts like this: "Delete row ID 123"... or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This callback will be called multiple times byJavaFX causing unnecessary rendering of each row just for the context menu, am I right?

Answer (score 18):

JavaFX 8 (with Lambda):

```
MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem("Menu item 1");
mi1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("Menu item 1");
    Object item = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("Selected item: " + item);
});

ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
menu.getItems().add(mi1);
table.setContextMenu(menu);
```

See also:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html

Comment: What library are you importing to use `Item`? Intellij doesn't suggest anything for it

Comment: @Robb1, Item is a class created by myself. It is whatever your table contains. Post edited. 
Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#getSelectedItem--

Comment: Nice and simple. The problem with this however is that the context menu is available wherever you click on the table, even outside of a cell :/