# Minimize panel button

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm working on this example of simple panel.

[image]

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private static BorderPane bp;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {


        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
        flow.setPadding(new Insets(50, 5, 5, 5));
        flow.setVgap(15);
        flow.setHgap(15);
        flow.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        HBox thb = new HBox();
        thb.setPadding(new Insets(13, 13, 13, 13));
        thb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gray");

        DropShadow ds = new DropShadow();
        ds.setOffsetY(3.0);
        ds.setOffsetX(3.0);
        ds.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setEffect(ds);
        bp.setPrefSize(600, 500);
        bp.setMaxSize(600, 500);

        bp.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  white;");
        bp.setTop(thb);
        flow.getChildren().add(bp);
        Scene scene = new Scene(flow, 1200, 800);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Can you help me to create button which minimizes the panel. I want when I click the button to shrink the size of the panel.

Comment: None of the code in there creates a button or has any functionality to minimize the "panel". Can you show what you've tried in order to solve the problem, and explain what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand basically what you trying to do. I think this might help you.

```
    final Button btnmin = new Button();
    flow.getChildren().add(btnmini)
    btnmin.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("mini.gif"))));

    btnmin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
          Stage stage = (Stage)btnmin.getScene().getWindow();
          stage.setIconified(true);
        }
    });
```